Writing data to a MIFARE card fails with 917E
I have an Android app that programs MIFARE cards (changes encryption mode from DES to AES, creates apps, writes some data to those apps - that sort of thing).
I'm using the standard WriteData command which is supposed to have several parameters:

Command byte (0x3D)
File ID byte
File offset
Amount of data that has to be added to the file
The data itself

It works fine with I'm trying to write small chunks of data (i.e. the data gets written correctly, the NFC card that I use does not report any CRC calculation problems, etc, etc)
The problems start when I need to write larger chunks of data (so that the card responds with 0x91AF, asking me to provide additional data frames). No matter how I calculate the CRC for a second data frame, the card always responds with 0x911E (which is an Integrity Error, according to the documentation).
So here's what I tried:

The CRC calculation for a first data frame works over the command byte + file id + length + offset + first piece of data (I'm limiting it to 28 bytes). So, naturally, I thought that the second data frame is supposed to have the same structure and the CRC has to be calculated in the same manner - but when I did that I received 0x917e, which is a length error
I looked over the documentation and I found on page 59 that subsequent data frames do not have the metadata (file id + length + offset) attached. So now I changed CRC calculation so that it's calculated over a command byte (0xAF) and a second piece of data, and I stopped adding metadata to the data frame. So the overall structure is now command byte + encrypted payload (which is a second data piece + CRC). The Length Error is gone, but the Integrity Error is raised
I tried changing the command byte used in CRC calculation to 0x3D, but send the command with 0xAF. Still the same error

I'm a bit at loss here since I can't find a simple example on how the data exchange between PICC and PCD is supposed to look like in case a sequence of bytes that does not fit into a single frame has to be written to a standard file. Does anyone have an idea of what might be wrong?

See the Desfire Tools for Android - this will guide you in finding the correct CRC: https://github.com/skjolber/desfire-tools-for-android. From my memory- I think the CRC is calculated and send just once.
